# Calculating Sinusoidal Equation From Irregularly Given Information

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image: Problem 22]

I solved this problem on my final exam review and came up with a working equation for 22.c), $$k(x) = 10 \sin\left(\frac \pi3x-\frac \pi6\right) - 3 $$ 
However, when I use $2\pi/b$ to check the period of the function, I get $6$, which is half the actual period, $12$, since the minimum value, $k(x) = -13$ has an $x$ value of $5$, and $k(x) =  7$ has an $x$ value of  $11$.

Am I not accounting for the $\times2$ change in the $x$ values?

Please help, Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks G Perez for making this look better

Comment: Is this question about mathematics or about Mathematica software?  If the former, it belongs in [math.se].

Comment: Mathematics, sorry, I originally asked in MAthematica but it is migrated

Comment: Do you by chance know the answer though? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $-10 sin[(x-2) \frac{\pi}{6}] - 3$, in which case k(15) = -8.

Mathematica is convenient for quickly evaluating the function:

```
Table[-10 Sin[(x - 2) Pi/6] - 3, {x, 1, 15, 2}]
```

and yields `{2, -8, -13, -8, 2, 7, 2, -8}`, as expected.  (The last term is the desired unknown element at `x = 15`.

Comment: Wait.....is the equation (Pi/6)x - (Pi/3)?????

Comment: The argument of `Sin` is `(Pi/6)x - (Pi/3)`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant thanks. I think I may have made a stupid mistake in copying my b and c answers (sin(bx-c)) to the actual equation

Answer (score 0):

Your formula does not agree with the table at $x=3$, for starters. And probably at other places.

As you have noted, if the outputs $-13$ and $7$ are $6$ input units apart, and they represent a low point and high point of a sine wave, and if we assume that they represent an adjacent such pair of extrema, then the period must be $12$. (You could also deduce the period is $12$ by seeing the output $2$ occurring at inputs $1,9$, and $13$.)

So you have $$A\sin(2\pi x/12 + \varphi)+B$$

Start from there, and use other information in the table to determine $A,B,\varphi$.

Comment: I derived A because -3 is 10 away from the min and the max. B and c (you represented it as a greek symbol) were from plugging in x and y values, where I go values for b - c and 3b - c.

Comment: Sorry, I represented your B with d and 2Pi/12 as b

Comment: My point is that your "$\frac{\pi}{3}x$" is wrong. I have it as "$2\pi x/12$", but you could write that as "$\frac{\pi}{6}x$".

Comment: Yes I realize now thanks!